# Trigger event on select element when option changed with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

On this page https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/squad/transfers there is a dropdown where you can select a player's maximum price. It then filters a table below to only show players with a price equal or less than the selected maximum price. With my Chrome extension I have added two buttons which change the selected option

```
/**
 * Increases the price of the /transfers maximum price filter.
 */
function increasePrice() {
  const priceFilter = document.getElementById('ismjs-element-price');
  if (priceFilter.selectedIndex === 0) return;
  priceFilter.selectedIndex -= 1;
  priceFilter.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}

/**
 * Decreases the price of the /transfers maximum price filter.
 */
function decreasePrice() {
  const priceFilter = document.getElementById('ismjs-element-price');
  if (priceFilter.selectedIndex === priceFilter.options.length - 1) return;
  priceFilter.selectedIndex += 1;
  priceFilter.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}

/**
 * Adds the increase and decrease price buttons for filtering players by the their maximum price to
 * the /transfers sidebar.
 */
function addPriceButtons() {
  const priceDiv = document.getElementById('ismr-price');
  if (priceDiv.classList.contains('price-filter')) return;

  priceDiv.className += ' price-filter';
  const increaseButton = document.createElement('div');
  const decreaseButton = document.createElement('div');

  increaseButton.className = 'price-change-button grid-center';
  increaseButton.textContent = '+';
  increaseButton.onclick = increasePrice;
  decreaseButton.className = 'price-change-button grid-center';
  decreaseButton.textContent = '-';
  decreaseButton.onclick = decreasePrice;

  priceDiv.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', increaseButton);
  priceDiv.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', decreaseButton);
}
```

which seems to work fine, as shown in the GIF below

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't actually change the players shown in the table. I thought that by adding

```
priceFilter.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

it would work fine. I've also tried 'click' and 'input', but these events don't do anything either.

[image]

I've also inspected the `select` element in Chrome's to see which event listeners it has, and if I could maybe make sense of it. Unfortunately the code is minified, so I can't really tell what to do.

Am I missing something? Where am I supposed to find out how the table is filtered in the first place and how can I trigger this myself?

Comment: The page could listen on a parent (looks likely judging by your screenshot) so try bubbling it by dispatching `new Event('change', {bubbles: true})` and maybe also same for `'input'`.

Comment: @wOxxOm this was it, thanks so much!